# How do I make these two threads run togeather?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class FileFinder {
    private static Timer timerThread;
    private static Find findThread;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        timerThread = new Timer(Integer.parseInt(args[3]));
        findThread = new Find(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
        Thread timer = new Thread(timerThread);
        Thread finder = new Thread(findThread);

        finder.start();
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Note: finder will find the file entered by a user 
       timer is supposed to run in parallel with the find thread and if the specified timeout exceeds than both threads must exit.

Approach I am following:-

**TIMER**

```
 @Override
    public void run() {
    newTime = startTime;
    System.out.println("Timer Running\n");
    System.out.println("TimeOut is:" + timeOut +"\n");
    while(true){
        if(newTime < startTime+timeOut){
            newTime=startTime+ System.currentTimeMillis();  
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }

    System.err.println("Cannot find");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

**FIND**

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running find");
        File searchDir = new File(this.searchLocation);
        UserFilter filter = new UserFilter(searchKeyword,searchType,pathOfSearchedFiles);

        /*for(String file : searchDir.list(filter)){
            pathOfSearchedFiles.add(searchDir+File.separator+file);
        }*/

        searchDir.list(filter);

        for(String f: pathOfSearchedFiles){
            System.out.println(f);  
        }
    }
```

My find thread is not getting time to work and timer thread is exiting the application.

Please suggest.

Comment: In java exists a synchronize keyword. For further informations http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm

Comment: You need some sort of synchronization based on timer? Your question is not clear now.

Comment: @Sasha, I want to run both of my threads togeather, timer thread is responsible for managing for how much time the finder thread should keep searching for files.

Comment: @Ankit this is a bad design I suppose. How will a timer thread terminate finder thread on deadline?

Comment: @ankit there can only one thread can run at a time

Comment: @keval, is it the same if a system has more than 1 cores? I have i5

Comment: @Ankit most processors are limited on the number of true simultaneous threads they can execute to the number of cores they have, but even that is a bad estimate due to shared resources and hardware. In theory you could have up to 4 simultaneous threads running on a 4-core processor.

Comment: @Ankit if you have i5 means more than one core and than two thread in your code should work fine, by default they should run together right .. but they are not running

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a problem in your while loop:

```
while(startTime < startTime+timeOut){
                startTime=startTime+ System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
```

This is an infinite loop....

Answer (score 2):

Your timer function doesn't do what you expect. It adds the current time to the start time and then requests that it's bigger than itself (unless timeout is negative). Chances are you're getting a overflow and that is why it is exiting early

Instead try something like:

```
@Override
public void run() {
        System.out.println("Timer Running");
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeOut;

        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(500);  //Set the granularity here to a suitable value
            catch(InterruptedException e){
            }
        }

        System.err.println("Cannot find");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your Find thread as a parametre to the timer to manage it:

**Main** :

```
 public class FileFinder {
    private static Timer timerThread;
    private static Find findThread;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        findThread = new Find(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
        Thread finder = new Thread(findThread);
        timerThread = new Timer(Integer.parseInt(args[3]),finder); // <-- here add parameter
        finder.start();
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

**TIMER**

```
 // You have finder as an attribute Thread finder;
    @Override
        public void run() {
        newTime = startTime;
        System.out.println("Timer Running\n");
        System.out.println("TimeOut is:" + timeOut +"\n");
        while(true){
            if(newTime < startTime+timeOut){
                newTime=startTime+ System.currentTimeMillis();  
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
        if(finder != null)
            finder.interrupt(); // <--- here you interrupt finder thread
        System.err.println("Cannot find");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: there is no way to immediately stop a thread. Any way you should check status in the cycle. And if so why did you decide to have separate thread to stop finder thread? You can just time in the cycle of finder and exit if time is exceeded. Like:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Running find");
    File searchDir = new File(this.searchLocation);
    UserFilter filter = new UserFilter(searchKeyword,searchType,pathOfSearchedFiles);

    /*for(String file : searchDir.list(filter)){
        pathOfSearchedFiles.add(searchDir+File.separator+file);
    }*/

    searchDir.list(filter);

    for(String f: pathOfSearchedFiles){
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= stopTime) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(f);  
    }
}
```